# How to nest components in a proper way

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm starting with EMBER.js, and there are some doubts that I have:

Let's say that I am creating a simple chat, just for the example. I have a left-side panel with a list of users, and a right-side panel with the messages sent.

I considered creating a *component* called: `users-list`, that displays a list of users. Every member of that list should be another *component* called `user`.

This means that a `user` *component* is responsible of drawing itself, with the user name, last sent message, name color, etc... (all are properties) and also has some actions in buttons beside its name: changeName, changeColor, leaveRoom.

While a `users-list` is responsible for maintaining a list of users and displaying them using the `user` component.

**So the questions here are:**

1. Is this the proper way to go?
2. If it is: How can I delete an item from the `users-list` component, from an action inside of the child `user` component (`leaveRoom` action)?
3. If not: How should I implement that? I'd like to keep responsibilities isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this the proper way to go?

Yes, it is. But you have to use hyphen in component name, so `user` component should become something like this: `user-component`.

> If it is: How can I delete an item from the users-list component, from
>   an action inside of the child user component (leaveRoom action)?

See [WORKING DEMO](https://ember-twiddle.com/18938dee2b816b70ff45?openFiles=users-list.component.js%2Cuser-component.component.js).

In `users-list` template pass an action (defined in `users-list`) to `user-component`:

```
{{#each model as |user|}}
    {{user-component model=user leaveRoom=(action 'leaveRoom')}}
{{/each}}
```

Action `leaveRoom` in `users-list`:

```
actions: {
  leaveRoom(user) {
    alert('User-list: user ' + user.name + ' wants to leave room.');
  }
}
```

Then, we have simple `user-component` template with button that fires an action `leaveRoom` of `user-component`:

```
{{model.name}} - <button {{action 'leaveRoom' model}}>Leave room</button>
```

Action `leaveRoom` in `user-component` calls action passed to component from `users-list`. So, `leaveRoom` in `user-component` looks like this:

```
actions: {
  leaveRoom(user) {
    this.get('leaveRoom')(user);
  }
}
```